# When I execute the following query, I get the message like ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select c.cust_id,
       c.company_name, 
       (select count(order_id) from orders 
        union 
        select count(order_id) from orderdetails)
from Orders o,
     Customer c,
     OrderDetails od;
```

Comment: Yes, because your inner select has a union that can return two different values, hence you get that error.  Do you want the sum of orders and order details?  Also you don't seem to specify how the Orders, Customers and OrderDetails should be joined, so that will be an outer join (it will join each row to every other row)

Comment: You're running a subquery to put a value into a single field in a single row. Clearly then, that subquery cannot have the potential to return more than one row...otherwise how can the database know which row to use in main row? As for fixing it...well we don't know anything about your database or your intentions...please provide a [mre] of the scenario. See also [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: if the both subquery returns same value , it will show one values. otherwise it will returns more rows . why are u using union ? when  you can directly count (o.order_id).

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.